# Howto add 2 signed-off to my git patches?

Tags: git

I want to generate a git patch with the command

```
git format-patch master -s
```

but the above command generate patches with my email (already defined) as signed-off. And Iwant to generate the patches with 2 emails as signed-off like this:

```
Signed-off-by: firstname1 lastname1 <person1@email1.com>
Signed-off-by: firstname2 lastname2 <person2@email1.com>
```

Note: I want to added it automatically via command line and not added it manually to the patch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change committer identity

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="John Doe" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=john.doe@skynet.com git format-patch master -s
```

This will produce (in every patch)

```
Signed-off-by: John Doe <john.doe@skynet.com>
```

To add an extra 'Signed-off-by' I'm afraid you have to use an external i.e.

```
sed -i '/Signed-off-by/ a\
Signed-off-by: Jane Doe <jane.doe@skynet.com>' *.patch
```

This will produce (in every patch)

```
Signed-off-by: John Doe <john.doe@skynet.com>
Signed-off-by: Jane Doe <jane.doe@skynet.com>
```